# How to combine client-only and server-only code in an integration test?

Tags: java, gwt, integration-testing

I'm using a mechanism to pass bootstrapping information embedded in
the host page (which is a servlet/jsp combination) from the server to
the client. The bootstrapping information contains vital information
that is required during client start up which saves one client/server
round trip and therefore speeds up application start up.

I'm using Gson to serialize the bootstrapping information and inject
it directly into a  tag in the host page. The information is
accessed on the client using [JS Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html). Because passing
long values from JS to Java isn't supported by GWT I'm using a custom
JsonSerializer which turns all longs/Longs into Strings.

All of this works fine but it is a little fragile. Therefore I'd love
to verify the correct behavior in an integration test which covers
both the server and the client side components. This is where I ran
into trouble: Gson (used in the server side component) isn't GWT
compatible and JS Overlay Types obviously aren't Java compatible.

My question is: Is it possible to write a GWTTestCase which runs some
parts of the code as pure Java (ie. on the integrated server)? If not,
do you have any other recommendations on how to test this?

Thanks a lot!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a servlet for you test using Gson, that you map using a `<servlet path="…" class="…" />` tag in a gwt.xml (make one specifically for your tests that inherits the one from your application/production-module); then write a GWTTestCase for the client-side.

Have a look at how GWT tests itself (RequestBuilder, GWT-RPC, FormPanel), e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/http/

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I didn't have time so far to implement your recommendations.